# Como copia o valor um DIV para outro DIV com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, div

O meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho uma página em html, e nessa página, tem 2 divs. no segundo div, eu tenho um javascript que armazena um valor em uma determinada variável.

O que eu quero, é exibir o valor dessa variável no primeiro div.

Vocês sabem como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens para percebermos melhor o problema?

Comment: "**div, eu tenho um javascript que armazena um valor em uma determinada variável.**" - isso está muito mal explicado. `div` não pode conter javascript.

Comment: Tá mal explicado mas pelo que eu entendi é como pegar o conteúdo do segundo div para primeiro div, se for, é esse código seguinte `$("#div1").html($("#div2").html())`, avisando que é Jquery

Answer (score 3):

Para criar em JavaScript Puro é só seguir este exemplo:

```js
// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML;
// Escrevendo em outro Elemento
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
texto.innerHTML = "Texto Copiado: " + elemento;
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  Exemplo
</div>
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Mas se for em jQuery é só seguir o exemplo do @Adriano-Resende:

```js
// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = $('#teste').html();
// Escrevendo em outro Elemento
var texto = $('#texto');
texto.html('Texto Copiado: ' + elemento);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
  Texto
</div>
<div id="texto"></div>
```